# How can I convert my list to be like this?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I convert my list to be like this?

My list:

[image: My list]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: where are id_kota nad id_cust value come from?

Comment: make new @eamirho3ein

Comment: what exactly goes from your list into that new data?

Comment: id => id_kota @eamirho3ein

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap(List<Area> list){
    return {
      "data": list.map((e) => {"id_kota": "${e.id,}", "id_cust": 0}).toList()
    };
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
var result = jsonEncode(toMap(areaPraktek));
print("result = $result"); //{"data": [{"id_kota":"86","id_cust":0},{"id_kota":"89","id_cust":0}]}
```

Comment: this is the result {data: {data: [{id_kota: 85, id_cust: 0}, {id_kota: 87, id_cust: 0}]}}

Comment: i want {"data":[{"id_kota":"63","id_cust":0},{"id_kota":"64","id_cust":0},{"id_kota":"65","id_cust":0}]}

Comment: not the same @eamirho3ein

Comment: can you edit your question and show me how to use this:?

Comment: did you use `result` in an other map ? or just print it?

Comment: Map<String, dynamic> toMap(List<Area> list) {
          return {
            "data": list.map((e) => {"id_kota": e.id, "id_cust": 0}).toList()
          };
        }

        print(toMap(event.areaPraktek));

Comment: result = flutter: {data: [{id_kota: 85, id_cust: 0}, {id_kota: 87, id_cust: 0}]}
 @eamirho3ein

Comment: @AhmedSalavy you are getting what you want ! you want  {data: [{id_kota: 85, id_cust: 0}, {id_kota: 87, id_cust: 0}]} and now you are getting it. right?

Comment: this is not the same as my question @eamirho3ein

Comment: you want only the new list or with map?

Comment: check new update.

Comment: {"data":[{"id_kota":"63","id_cust":0},{"id_kota":"64","id_cust":0},{"id_kota":"65","id_cust":0}]} i just want a result like this @eamirho3ein

Comment: what do you see when you print result with first approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249983/discussion-between-eamirho3ein-and-ahmed-salavy).

Comment: result flutter: result = {data: [{id_kota: 85, id_cust: 0}, {id_kota: 87, id_cust: 0}]}
flutter: results = [{id_kota: 85, id_cust: 0}, {id_kota: 87, id_cust: 0}]